# How to make an element transparent so its background is 2 layers behind?

Tags: html, css

I have an animated background (background), a div on it with a background-color (A), and another div in it (B). I want B to be transparent so through it we see the animated background, but B is in A, which already have a background-color.

[image: What is to be achieved]

Any ideas to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using the CSS clip-path property as long as you only wanted 'B' to be the cutout of 'A', in which case you wouldn't need 'B' at all.

HTML:

```
<div class="animated-bg">
  <div class="inner-a">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.animated-bg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner-a {
  background-color: white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

Otherwise if you wanted 'B' to hold something e.g text you could absolute position it behind clipped 'A' and give it a transparent background.

Something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="animated-bg">
  <div class="inner-b">
    hello
  </div>
  <div class="inner-a">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.animated-bg {
  background-image: url(http://www.animateit.net/data/media/august2009/twi.gif);
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner-a {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.inner-b {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
```

Clippy is really good to get the right sized clip: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

- Fiddle 1st Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fjr7qvcm/1/
- Fiddle 2nd Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fjr7qvcm/4/

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you have three layers: Background, Div A and Div B. Div A + B need to be transparent to be able to see the animated background. Have you tried using the CSS property "opacity"?

```
div {
    opacity: .3; /* Anything betweet 0 - 1 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Check this out for more information about opacity https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a div like a mask to hide background of its parent. So alternatively you can change the `background-color` of `div.A` to be `border` so that you can have the transparent effect like the following example

```css
.out {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px);
  height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.A {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  height: 100px;
}

.B {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="B">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever but it's a tip that cannot fit my situation because real case is not like the draw I put. I really want div B to be transparent so through it we could see the animated background and not the background-color of div A :/

Comment: Fine. Then you have to go with lewis briffa's answer as it works perfectly. You need to ad some browser specific attributes for mozilla, ie and opera as it now works perfectly in chrome